# How can I do automatic redirects to canonical URLs as defined by Yoast SEO?

Tags: redirect, plugin-wp-seo-yoast, rel-canonical

This client is using Yoast SEO (the free version) to specify primary categories for posts, a feature not available in the WordPress core. They discovered recently, via an SEO report, that the same post can be accessed multiple ways by changing the category slug in the URL. The WordPress permalink settings are set to a custom structure, as follows: `/company/news-views/%category%/%postname%/` So, while the canonical URL of a post might be `/company/news-views/sustainability/blah-blah-blah/`, where `sustainability` is the primary category, you can also access the same post via `/company/news-views/aircraft-management/blah-blah-blah/`, where `aircraft-management` is another category that has been set on the post. I've checked the source HTML of both URLs and both have the same canonical URL meta tag. That is, the HTML looks something like:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.com/company/news-views/sustainability/blah-blah-blah/" class="yoast-seo-meta-tag" />
```

My question is, how can we force an automatic redirect to the canonical URL if a non-canonical URL is entered? One would think that Yoast would have this feature. (Maybe it's only available in the premium version?) I'm aware of the `redirect_canonical` filter, but I'm not sure how to obtain the canonical URL by using that filter, especially since the filter does not supply a `$post` or `$post_id` parameter. The `redirect_canonical` function fires before the global `$post` variable is set. Or perhaps I need to override a different filter/action, like maybe `pre_get_posts`?